# Evaluate line integral using Green's theorem. I think I made an error.

Tags: integration, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I think I've made a huge mistake...

So from my understanding I can evaluate the area to the left of a curve using Green's theorem which states taht the line integral is = to this special double integral right?

> Evaluate $\int_c F(r) \cdot dr$ counterclockwise around the boundary.

3. $F = [x^{2}e^{y}, y^{2}e^{x}$ and R the rectangle with vertices: (0,0), (2,0), (2,3), (0,3)

So clearly the rectangle has an area of 6, unsure how this will play later.

so $$F1 = x^{2}e^{y} $$

$$F2 = y^{2}e^{x} $$

because $\frac{d}{dx} e^{y} = e^{y}$ and so treating $x^{2}$ as constant: $x^{2} \frac{d}{dy}e^{y} = x^{2}e^{y}$

$$\frac{d}{dy}F1 = x^{2}e^{y}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}F2 = y^{2}e^{x}$$

$\therefore$

$$\int \int_R (x^{2}e^{y} - y^{2}e^{x} dx dy$$

but this doesn't look elegant or nice....

Comment: One of them needs to be differentiated wrt y not x. Anyway it does look like the integral you need to do in this question is a bit messy but not really all that bad.

Comment: I made a typo. Is that right? Mind showing me the way?

Comment: $\int_0^2 \int_0^3 x^2 e^y - y^2 e^x dy dx$ just...is what it is. It's two straightforward single integrals to do.

Comment: Why is 0 to 3 the inner integral?

Comment: Doesn't have to be, since the region is just a rectangle, but the $dy$ integral, whichever one it is, is definitely 0 to 3.